# GreyScale translation issues

Tags: python, image-processing, opencv, image-manipulation

I'm getting the following error:

```
cv.error: Incorrect number of channels for this conversion code
```

from the following piece of code:

```
cv.CvtColor(frame, gray, cv.CV_BGR2GRAY)
```

any recommendations?

Comment: If you are searching for a more accurate answer, you should provide the source code of your implementation. What kind of image is it? JPEG? PNG? BMP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the number of channels of `frame` and `gray`.  Either use a debugger, or put this line before the conversion:

```
printf("frame.nChannels: %d gray.nChannels: %d\n", frame.nChannels, gray.nChannels);
```

`frame` needs to be 3 channels (RGB).  `gray` needs to be 1 channel.  Anything other than that and the conversion will fail.  In this case:

- You can force `frame` to **always** be loaded as RGB by passing `cv.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR` as the second argument to `cv.LoadImage`, if you're loading it from a file
- Make sure when you create `gray`, you specify that it only has 1 channel, e.g. `gray=cv.CreateImage(cv.GetSize(frame), frame.depth, 1)`

Look at [OpenCV API](https://picoforge.int-evry.fr/projects/svn/gpucv/opencv_doc/2.1/opencv.pdf) for the respective functions for more info.  The section on Python is Chapter 3, but since the Python wrappers simply re-use the underlying C code, the first part is also relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `frame` is not an RGB image, is it?